# Text rendering with Gstreamer (appsrc, textrender)

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I am trying to render text with GStreamer. The text is a timestamp which I want to update for each frame of my video source. The timestamp will then be overlaid over the video stream captured from a v4l2src.

The problem is that only the very first timestamp is shown on the display output. The pipeline keeps on running, pad probe being called and pushing data into the appsrc.
I cannot see any error in the debug output (GST_DEBUG=4).

Note, I do not want to use the timeoverlay or clockoverlay plugins as I will use a hardware-accelerated plugin available on my SoC to do the overlay.
I just want to produce a video stream with the text that I can then pipe into my overlay plugin.

These are the pipelines in the test app:

```cpp
auto src_pipe = gst_parse_launch("videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,format=YUY2 ! fakesink name=camera");

auto time_pipe = gst_parse_launch("appsrc name=time_overlay format=3 is-live=true do-timestamp=true ! text/x-raw,format=utf8 ! textrender ! video/x-raw,format=ARGB,framerate=30/1,width=720,height=480 ! autovideoconvert ! autovideosink");
```

And I use the following pad probe to generate the text:

```cpp
   auto src = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(src_pipe), "camera");
   auto time_appsrc = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(time_pipe), "time_overlay");
   auto pad = gst_element_get_static_pad (src, "sink");
   gst_pad_add_probe (pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER, (GstPadProbeCallback) cb_have_data, time_appsrc, NULL);
   gst_object_unref (pad);

static void push_time(GstElement *time_appsrc)
{
   GstFlowReturn ret;
   GstMapInfo map;

   struct timespec tp;
   clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp);

   static std::string time;
   time = "The time " + std::to_string(tp.tv_sec) + "sec " + std::to_string(tp.tv_nsec) + "ns";

   auto buffer = gst_buffer_new_and_alloc (time.size());

    GST_BUFFER_TIMESTAMP (buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale (1, GST_SECOND, 25);
    GST_BUFFER_DURATION (buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale (1, GST_SECOND, 25);

   gst_buffer_map (buffer, &map, GST_MAP_WRITE);

   memcpy(map.data, time.c_str(), time.size());

   gst_buffer_unmap (buffer, &map);

   g_signal_emit_by_name (time_appsrc, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);

   gst_buffer_unref (buffer);
}

static GstPadProbeReturn cb_have_data (GstPad *pad, GstPadProbeInfo *info, gpointer user_data)
{
   GstMapInfo map;
   GstBuffer *buffer;
   GstElement *time_appsrc = (GstElement *)user_data;

   buffer = GST_PAD_PROBE_INFO_BUFFER (info);

   push_time(time_appsrc);

   GST_PAD_PROBE_INFO_DATA (info) = buffer;

   return GST_PAD_PROBE_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I was setting the timestamp of the buffer to a fixed value... Removing the line below makes it work as expected.

GST_BUFFER_TIMESTAMP (buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale (1, GST_SECOND, 25);